# Ionic 2 How to Change Modal Height and Width

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a page on my application that has a Modal Page and I want to change the size of that page, I try to use the model property to change it but it will change the size of all the other ones  and I want to have different models with different sizes

```
$modal-inset-min-width
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this into your `app.scss`:

```
.my-modal {
    height: 50%!important;
    width: 50%!important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I used the suggested approach to launch a modal with 50% height, but I found the problem of not having enabled the backdrop.

```
//app.scss

.my-modal {
  height: 50%!important;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

outputs:

[image]

so I ended up with:

```
//app.scss

@include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
.my-modal {
    ion-backdrop {
      visibility: visible !important;
    }
    .modal-wrapper {
      border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
      overflow: hidden;
      top: 50%;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50%;
    }
  }
}
```

that output these views:

[image: iPhone 6 cap]
[image: iPad cap]

I used the breakpoint mixin to keep the modal behavior in 768+ px (tablets, etc).

Hope helps somebody.

Answer (score 2):

If you see inside `create` method of `ModalController`, it is:

```
create(component: any, data?: any, opts?: ModalOptions): Modal;
```

And here is `ModalOptions`:

```
export interface ModalOptions {
    showBackdrop?: boolean;
    enableBackdropDismiss?: boolean;
    enterAnimation?: string;
    leaveAnimation?: string;
    cssClass?: string;
}
```

So, just add a class to your modal like that:

```
let modal = this.mModalController.create("YourModalPage","Your data",{
    cssClass: "my-modal"
})
```

And now you can style for your modal by `.my-modal` class

Comment: I try to add the class in page.scss like this  .my-modal{
    
    height: 50%!important;
    width: 50%!important;
          } but it did not work

Comment: Did you create your modal like above? And was the class added to your element?

Answer (score 1):

**Put his Code into your app.scss file**

```
modal-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media not all and (min-height: 600px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  ion-modal ion-backdrop {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-height: 0px) and (min-width: 0px) {
  .modal-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modal Controller takes a custom css

```
let moreInfoModal = this.modalCtrl.create(DesktopMoreInfoPage, {
  titles: title,
  images: image,
  description: description
}, {cssClass: 'custom-class'});
moreInfoModal.present();
```

Then in your app.scss file

```
.custom-class {
//your styling goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom css

```
ion-modal.my-modal {
  padding: 10vh 10vw;
}
```

Custom ts

```
this.modalCtrl.create(pageName, {myParam:item}, { cssClass: 'my-modal' });
```